# Is it possible to connect a git submodule to a specific commit on a branch on the main project?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I have this situation with `git version 2.8.0.windows.1`.

I have one "**release**" branch of the main project and I push there everytime I've a new release.

This project has a submodule that is developed in parallel, so I expect many commits there.

**Project Master** branch and **Submodule Master** branches goes ahead (almost) in parallel.

*Master Commit 1 => Master Commit 2 => Master Commit 3 => Master Commit 4

Submodule Commit 1 => Submodule Commit 2 => Submodule Commit 3 => Submodule Commit 4*

In this case *Master Commit 4* is aligned with *Submodule Commit 4*.

The issue arises when someone tries to get the **release** branch too late.
So if I push the **release** branch at *Master Commit 1* and someone pull release branch when we are at *Master Commit 4* we have a misalignment (because **release** is related to *Master Commit 1*, while now we are on *Submodule Commit 4*).

The solution I see is to coerce somehow *Submodule Commit 1* to **release** branch, but I don't know how yet.

I know that a great solution would be just to add a branch or tag on the submodule as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/how-can-i-specify-a-branch-tag-when-adding-a-git-submodule).

But I've no authority over the submodule repository, so it won't be easy for me to set branches or tags there.

Are there any workarounds to coerce a **specific submodule commit** on my release branch and **not just a submodule branch/tag**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how submodules work anyway so I don't understand your problem. Let's me try to enhance or fix your workflow. You need every commit in the `release` branch points to the corresponding commit in the submodule, right? This is easy: before making commits in the `release` branch update the submodule, checkout the correct commit in the submodule and commit the change in superproject:

```
# In the superproject
git checkout release

cd subdir # into the submodule
git checkout master # reconcile detached HEAD
git pull origin master # update the submodule
git checkout some-sha1 # if you don't want the latest commit in master

cd .. # back into superproject
git add subdir
git commit -m "Update submodule"
```

Now everyone who `git clone --recursive` the superproject gets the submodule pointed to the correct commit for every commit in the branch `release`.

Comment: What if I need to do it on my machine without recloning? I tried `git checkout release` `git pull origin release`, but it doesn't restore the submodule to the release version (I still have the master submodule). I tried with `git submodule sync` with no success too.

Comment: [`git pull --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-recurse-submodulesyeson-demandno) or `git submodule update`.